# Evaluating $\int_A y^2 dA$

Tags: integration

I would like some explanation regarding the following integral which is not familiar to me:

$$\int_A y^2 dA$$

where $y$ could be a function of $A$ and $A$ is cross section.

It's named $I_z$ in the course book and then in a few exercises, numbers are substituted for $y$ and $A$ but I don't get where they came from.

Comment: It would help if you actually gave a problem where this came up. Presumably the $I$ stands for inertia though.

Comment: @Batman: This is a problem in the book titled "mechanics of materials", I think no one on this site is interested in the concept. Just want to know more about the integral itself.

Comment: Well all we can tell you without that is to substitute in what $dA$ is ( $dx\ dy$, for example) and then carry out the multidimensional integral a la Calc 2.

Comment: @Batman: Thanks, then do we integrate with respect to $x$ or $y$? And what's the role of $A$ beneath the integral sign?

Comment: $dA=dxdy=rdrd\phi...$ is the area element. $\int_A$ specifies the range of A, e.g.$\int_A=\int_{-1}^{1}dx\int_{-1}^{1}dy...$

Comment: @mike: I still don't get it, I don't know how to evaluate such integrals. An example would be nice.

Comment: Have you taken multivariable calculus? Sometimes known as calculus III.

Comment: @Fantini: Currently I am studying MS in Comutper Science and we didn't have to take such a course or at least I don't recall having taken it.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you may calculate the inertial moment in z direction with respect to the rotation of a disk with radius 1 and uniform mass density $\rho$:

$$I_z=\int_A \rho r^2 dA=\rho\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{1}(r^2)rdr=\frac{\pi}{2} \rho$$

Comment: I think I get it now, but I have to double check  the equation O had in the course book and make sure I can do it the same way. (congratulation for being a 1k user and thank you for your answer =)